# Grid Scruffy products, leaping out of the area, css float: left:

Tags: html, css

I am creating a grid of products where they getting left aligned and always getting in this way: https://i.stack.imgur.com/88coJ.jpg

this class would be in charge of organizing the product this way:

> > **.center_conteudo ul.Dot_ListaProdutosULClass li.Dot_ListaProdutosLIClass** {
> >
> > width: 188px;
> >
> > min-height: 218px;
> >
> > margin: 0 12px 30px 0;
> >
> > float: left;
> >
> > background: url("../imagens/produto_img_prateleira.png") no-repeat 0px 125px;
> >
> > }

The final form is getting that way
http://bit.ly/1nUyEJo

HELP-ME PLEASE! THANKS ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a fixed grid with four elements per row, and you want every 5th element to break onto a new row, you can use nth-child:

```
element:nth-child(4n - 3) {
    clear: both;
}
```

In your example case, that's:

```
.center_conteudo ul.Dot_ListaProdutosULClass li.Dot_ListaProdutosLIClass:nth-child(4n - 3) {
    clear: both;
}
```

Note that some older versions of IE do not support the :nth-child selector.